# Examples of using a circular polarizer filter for LED display

Tags: led, light, display

I was looking for ways to increase the contrast of a LED-based seven-segment display like [this](https://www.tinytronics.nl/shop/en/display/segment/robotdyn-segment-display-module-4-character-clock-red-tm1637-mini) against indoor ambient light, and [found this comment on EEVblog](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/manufacture/choosing-a-filter-for-a-7-segment-led-display/msg1677188/#msg1677188) suggesting using circular polarizing filters. The basic idea is that

> when circularly polarised light gets reflected (off the surface of the display), the reflection is polarised in the opposite direction, and so gets attenuated.

Are there visual examples of circular polarizers being used on LED displays to attenuate ambient light? I'd like to see how they look before purchasing them, but haven't found anything so far.

Bonus question: is this technique commonly used? If not, what is usually done to achieve the same effect? e.g. in clock radios or other consumer equipment.

Comment: 3D glasses from a movie theatre in your area probably use circular polarizing fiters ... you may even have a pair ... I've kept mine ... I'll look for an LED display and post a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polarizing filters are only useful for rejecting [specular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection) light reflected from a smooth surface. Indoor light tends to be mostly diffuse, and most LED displays are given a matt or semi-matt finish to reduce specular reflections.

I don't know of any LED display filters that use circular polarizing filters. Most use colored plastic (acrylic). Some are etched to make reflections more diffuse, or coated to absorb light rather than reflect it.

A colored filter works by attenuating light outside the bandwidth of the LED. Since ambient light has to go through the filter in both directions the attenuation is doubled, while the LED light is not significantly reduced. However in-band reflected light is not significantly attenuated by the filter either, which reduces contrast.

To improve contrast a gray filter may be applied, which reduces the LED output but reduces in-band ambient light more because it goes through the filter twice. With modern high-efficiency LEDs the reduced LED output can easily be compensated for by increasing LED current. A single filter can do both jobs simply by being 'deeper', because the stronger filtering also significantly increases in-band attenuation.

Another technique that can help with red LED displays is to use a 'purple' filter that lets some blue light through. This works by using the eye's ability to distinguish color to tell the difference between lit (red) and unlit (purple) areas.

Here is an example of a purple filter compared to a red LED (from [Agilent App note 1015](https://hpmemoryproject.org/an/pdf/an_1015.pdf)):-

[image]

Note how the red filter band is deliberately arranged to be on the edge of the LED output, which produces some 'gray' attenuation as well as having a sharp cutoff at shorter wavelengths. At longer wavelengths the eye already has less response so a sharp cutoff on the right is not needed.

In bright sunlight getting enough LED light to overcome diffuse reflection can be a problem, so a smooth filter surface often works better - unless sunlight reflects directly off it. Depending how the display is mounted, it may be possible to prevent direct reflection at normal viewing angles by tilting the filter, or the display may be recessed into the device or have a hood over it to stop direct light hitting it.

Answer (score 1):

For the bonus question:

What is commonly used is a slightly darkened transparent plastic or filter.  Think sunglasses.  They are not typically polarized.

Comment: What is commonly used is a plastic filter the same color as the LED.  It only passes the light from the LED and blocks other colors.  That makes for very good contrast.

Comment: @JRE brown and black tints are very common especially with blue and white LEDs. Also  cars use a dark tint for their VFD displays.