# Mechanical design of a 7 segment display

Tags: led, display, enclosure, materials, electro-mechanical

If I want to custom design a 7 segment display, I can design a pcb with LEDs etcetera, but where could I find guides on how to design the shroud (shrouding the LEDs from each other, so they don't light each other up, placing diffusers shaped like lines on top so they display as individual segments, and providing insulation from users' finger (grease) on the device which could be (thermally) problematic I believe)?

Guides tend to simply state how to use a commercial off the shelf 7 segment display or how to place exposed LEDs in a figure 8 but totally unshrouded.

I'm less sure how to make mixed materials in precise placements.

(Despite the discussion of a part of the design of an electrical component, does this need to go to mechanical engineering?)

Comment: Commercial product or DIY? Most people don't make their own small 7-segment displays.

Comment: Heat is no problem unless you run it so hard it gets hot, of course

Comment: The book you want is by Hewlett-Packard: *Optoelectronics: Fiber-Optics Applications Manual*, 2nd edition, 0-07-028606-X. Everything you need to know. There's a whole chapter just on "Contrast Enhancement for LED Displays." And that's not all that's useful in there. They go into intimate detail, in a number of different places, about improving visibility with custom display designs using discrete LEDs. If you can't find the book (I bought a lot of them from the used market a while back), then I may be able to provide some digested info here.

Comment: Hmm. [Someone at Ebay has one here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/371768282105). And here I'd thought I'd cornered the market. ;)

Comment: https://archive.org/details/HewlettPackard-OptoelectronicsDesignersCatalog1984OCR/mode/2up (Thank you.)

Comment: @user253751 : DIY wearing the costume of commercial..

Comment: Buy a product that does what you're describing.   Take it apart.  Learn.

Comment: @kando No, that's not the book I'm thinking of. Not by a long-shot.

Comment: @kando Ah so you want to make something DIY but make it *look* commercial/professional. In which case, I think you'll find that precise building and cutting matters a lot more than the materials used. You can use literally anything that blocks light that can be cut to shape. An art supplies store near me sells sheets of black paper or black polypropylene (plastic) in several different sizes, which would be good for this. (Paper would be more environmentally friendly, but might not be opaque enough - would have to try it and see). Would also suggest comparing black vs white separators.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a good one, if not sufficiently detailed about your specific needs. I can't write what I will do here below as a comment, unfortunately. So I'm adding it as an answer even if it's not a complete solution for you.

Here's Figure 6.1-2 from HP's *"Optoelectronics: Fiber-Optics Applications Manual"*, 2nd edition, 0-07-028606-X:

[image]

This is an LED display exposed to artificial lighting (not bright sunlight, for sure, which may require louvered filters and shading, as well) and it shows what can be achieved using nothing more than an appropriate ***plastic*** optical filter.

Specifying such a simple plastic filter isn't difficult but it does require wavelength and intensity knowledge of the LED emitters you will be using (and more, such as dispersion angles.) It also requires knowledge of the environment within which it will be used. Obviously, if you intend use in bright sunlight the details will be quite different (and more extreme) than if you intend use within a room lit with artificial lighting.

Circularly polarized filters can greatly reduce the amount of ambient light that reaches through the filter, bounces off your board, and then escapes back out to interfere with human viewing. It does so because the ambient light must pass twice through the filter, while LED emitted light passes just once.

There are many other useful techniques. So I strongly recommend that you buy the book I mentioned (used, only, sadly.)

I had directed you to Chapter 6. Here's a fair-use copy of the first two paragraphs in that chapter:

[image]

The chapter sections are as follows:

- 6.0 Contrast Enhancement for LED Displays
- 6.1 Contrast and Contrast Ratio
- 6.2 Eye Response, Peak Wavelength and Dominant Wavelength
- 6.3 Filter Transmittance
- 6.3.1 Plastic Filters
- 6.3.2 Optical Glass Filters
- 6.4 Wavelength Filtering
- 6.4.1 Filtering Standard Red Displays (\$\lambda=655\:\text{nm}\$)
- 6.4.2 Filtering High-Efficiency Red Displays (\$\lambda=635\:\text{nm}\$)
- 6.4.3 Filtering Yellow Displays (\$\lambda=583\:\text{nm}\$)
- 6.4.4 Filtering Green Displays (\$\lambda=565\:\text{nm}\$)
- 6.5 Reduction of Reflective Ambient Light as Provided by a Contrast Filter
- 6.5.1 Effectiveness of a Wavelength Filter in an Ambient of Artificial Lighting
- 6.5.2 Effectiveness of a Wavelength Filter in Daylight Ambients
- 6.6 Special Wavelength Filters and Filters in Combination
- 6.6.1 The Purple Contrast Filter for Red LED Displays
- 6.6.2 Filters in Combination
- 6.7 Louvered Filters
- 6.8 Circular Polarizing Filters
- 6.9 Anti-Reflection Filters, Mounting Bezels and Other Suggestions

And that's just Chapter 6.

Comment: The textbook opened further [questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669474/led-7-segment-display-segment-housing-diffusion-and-reflectance), particularly surrounding optimizing optical efficiency in the construction of the housing, before the 'shrouding', which I now understand to be contrast enhancement through the use of concepts such as specific wavelength filters, neutral-grey density (broadband) filters, circular polarizers, and anti-reflection (anti-glare) coatings.

Comment: @kando I see they closed the question. I also see that you got the book!! I hope you are enjoying it. I'll look at the closed question when I get a moment. And yes, good design for LED display visibility is an engineering field all its own. But at least you are holding a book that attempts some coverage of the topic. Such are like hens' teeth: difficult to find.

Comment: Interestingly, several of those chapters appear to have been copied more or less verbatim with occasional updates, as uncovered by some references on other questions; I'll try to link them:

Comment: @kando There are a number of contributors to the book's 1st and 2nd editions. And likely some of the material was published in periodicals, earlier. Stuff like this doesn't just suddenly show up all at once. It comes out in drips and drabs. But that doesn't mean there wasn't a lot of work involved in tethering all of the sources together. For example, every single circuit idea was built, tested, and validated prior to publication of the 2nd edition. So everything they talk about, they built. That alone makes the book a solid piece of work of its own. I'd be interested in what you find, though.

Comment: Ch 6: Contrast Enhancement and Ch 11: Sunlight Viewable LED Displays appear in [Agilent Application Note 1015](https://hpmemoryproject.org/an/pdf/an_1015.pdf) (1999). It was referenced in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542642/examples-of-using-a-circular-polarizer-filter-for-led-display).

Comment: Ch 7: Photometry and Radiometry appears in [Avago Application Brief D-004](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/5963-7073E) (2010). I came across it in google searching before posting to stackexchange.

Comment: @kando Thanks. I've book-marked them. Later, I'll compare content. The Avago one would seem to claim original material dated long, long after the book and without referencing the book. If it contains material lifted from the book without reference, that would be at the very least somewhat dishonest. But thanks again for the links!

Comment: Not too dishonest it turns out — The associated portion of Hewlett Packard became [Agilent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agilent_Technologies) in 1999. The path from there to Avago to [Broadcom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcom_Inc.) more recently has many more stopping points along the way, as detailed in the history section of the link.

Comment: @kando This may be routine in business but the Avago paper also specifies 2010 on it. That would normally be taken by readers as being the copyright/ownership date. Certainly, no one would imagine they need to do a literature search going back another 30 years. This kind of behavior is considered "bad" in scholarly communities and would likely *permanently* injure a reputation. Others certainly can own the rights -- Nature magazine, for example. But it's plagiarism to remove authorship. I can't see a way of escaping that problem here. The authors were credited in the book, as should be.

Answer (score 3):

7-segment displays treat each segment as a light pipe. The LED light pipes are illuminated at one side and transmit light through to the front. So, the basic design is the same as a light pipe with a diffuser at the end.

The display housing is designed to block light from adjacent segments so that there isn't 'bleed-through' between them; alternatively the assembly is potted in an opaque material.

As far as protecting them from touch, generally the best way is to put a sheet of material in front of them. A popular approach is for this material to be dark ('dead front') so the display packages are concealed, but the lit segments shine through.

Comment: Small LED displays have evolved to have one LED per segment to be as cheap and efficient as possible. Old or larger displays may use more than one LED per segment.

Answer (score 2):

CO2 lasers are nowadays easily accessable, so an easy way is to cut one sheet with openings for the LEDs out of black acrylic, so that the shape creates walls around the segments.  The first sheet needs to be ~10 mm thick, so the led light hits a bigger area.

The next layer would be a diffuser material of opaque white acrylic. A thin layer will diffuse the light less. If you use a thick material, yet another non-translucent layer is needed to sharpen the edges of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done it at home is to either 3D print or laser-cut the exterior of the light pipes from a dark material (the "dark field" between the segments), then fill the light pipes themselves with epoxy glue or "clear" RTV silicone - both work as reasonable diffusers it seems. The light pipe filler can be colored with a dye to act as an optical filter. The "dark field" really needs to be dark then - not merely gray, but "pitch black". Then a separate optical filter in front is not necessary. But it's recommended.